# Why not work LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Tags: 16.04, shared-library

I couldn't understand why following command not work. LD_LIBRARY is not parsed collectly.

```
~:$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/usr/local/Qt5.10.0/5.10.0/gcc_64/lib; sudo /sbin/ldconfig -N -v $(sed 's/:/ /' <<< $LD_LIBRARY_PATH) |grep ^/
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/usr/local/Qt5.10.0/5.10.0/gcc_64/lib: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /lib/i686-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/nvidia-384' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib32/nvidia-384' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/nvidia-384' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib32/nvidia-384' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

/usr/local/cuda/lib64:
/opt/lib/alembic/lib:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot:
/lib/i386-linux-gnu:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu:
/usr/local/lib:
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Cannot stat /usr/lib32/nvidia-384/libOpenGL.so/usr/lib/nvidia-384:
: No such file or directory/usr/lib32/nvidia-384:

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

/opt/lib/ocio/lib:
/opt/lib/oiio/lib:
/opt/lib/osd/lib:
/opt/lib/osl/lib:
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib32:
/lib32/ld-2.23.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

/usr/lib32:
/lib:
/usr/lib:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/sse2: (hwcap: 0x0000000004000000)
/usr/lib/nvidia-384/tls: (hwcap: 0x8000000000000000)
/usr/lib32/nvidia-384/tls: (hwcap: 0x8000000000000000)
```

Each directory is right directory. Following command is work.

```
~:$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64; sudo /sbin/ldconfig -N -v $(sed 's/:/ /' <<< $LD_LIBRARY_PATH) |grep ^/
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /lib/i686-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/nvidia-384' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib32/nvidia-384' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/nvidia-384' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib32/nvidia-384' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

/usr/local/cuda/lib64:
/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:
/opt/lib/alembic/lib:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot:
/lib/i386-linux-gnu:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu:
/usr/local/lib:
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Cannot stat /usr/lib32/nvidia-384/libOpenGL.so: No such file or directory/usr/lib/nvidia-384:

/usr/lib32/nvidia-384:
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

/opt/lib/ocio/lib:
/opt/lib/oiio/lib:
/opt/lib/osd/lib:
/opt/lib/osl/lib:
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib32/ld-2.23.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring
/lib32:

/usr/lib32:
/lib:
/usr/lib:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/sse2: (hwcap: 0x0000000004000000)
/usr/lib/nvidia-384/tls: (hwcap: 0x8000000000000000)
/usr/lib32/nvidia-384/tls: (hwcap: 0x8000000000000000)
```

I am using ubuntu 16.04. Who knows the reason ?

Thanks.

```
~:$ ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.23-0ubuntu10) 2.23
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

Comment: What is your end goal here? likely the variable is not parsed correctly because your `sed` command only replaces the first colon separator. But AFAIK `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not meant to be used that way - it's used to provide *additional* paths that are *not* cached by `ldconfig`.

Comment: "Can't stat /usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/usr/local/Qt5.10.0/5.10.0/gcc_64/lib: No such file or directory". The list of LD_LIBRARY_PATH is separated with ":". ldd(?) does not parsing the list in the first command. Second command is working. It include "/usr/local/cuda/lib64" and "/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64". My goal is that "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/usr/local/Qt5.10.0/5.10.0/gcc_64/lib" command have to work. But not working to me. I want to know the reason.